# SQL Replace() function on a select or variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, replace

```
insert into PendingEmails (Subject,Body,ToEmail,PendingEmailStatusID)
select REPLACE( select subject from dbo.EmailTemplates where ID  = 7 ), '[CallID]'), (select Body from dbo.EmailTemplates where ID  = 7) ,contact.Email  ,5 
FROM  inserted AS i inner join Calls on i.CallID = Calls.CallId inner join Contact on calls.ContactID = Contact.ContactID
where contact.Email is not null and  contact.Email <> ''
```

I want to replace '[CallID]' in the subject with a value. that syntax is not working.
I also tried using a variable, wont work either.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into PendingEmails (Subject)
select REPLACE(subject, '[CallID]', @callid)
from dbo.EmailTemplates
where ID  = 7
```

I can't see where you are joining to the call table to get calls.callid, have you already stored it into a variable?

You can skip the variable if you have a subquery that will produce it (bracket the scalar subquery)

```
insert into PendingEmails (Subject)
select REPLACE(subject, '[CallID]', (select callid from calls where id=9))
from dbo.EmailTemplates
where ID = 7
```

Or JOIN it

```
insert into PendingEmails (Subject)
select REPLACE(e.subject, '[CallID]', c.callid)
from dbo.EmailTemplates e
join calls c on c.id=9
where e.ID = 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some parenthesis shenanigans:

```
insert into PendingEmails (Subject) 
select REPLACE(( select subject from dbo.EmailTemplates where ID = 7 ), '[CallID]' , calls.callid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  However, I think Richard has the better answer.  I'd go with that instead.

Comment: your right.. i first tried this and it works so I hit acceded, Now I tried the other one it's nicer... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO PendingEmails (Subject) 
SELECT REPLACE(subject, '[CallID]' , calls.callid)
    FROM dbo.EmailTemplates 
 WHERE ID = 7
```

Comment: where does calls.callid come from?